# Hashcat with md5 and Mask

Tags: hashcat

I'm trying to connect to my meter by using some open-source software, all the meter supports the dlms-cosem standard. But the problem is the meter disconnected due to a failed security check.

After some research about the issue, I found the encryption method:

```
data(F [ StoC] = MD5[ StoC || Hls-secret]).
```

The meter is disconnecting because of the wrong value HLS-secret set by open-source software.

So, I wanted to find this parameter by using hashcat to retrieve it from the plaintext of `F [ StoC ]`.

After I sniff the communication between the manufacturer software and the meter, I managed to get:

```
StoC: 852F8855BBD04A34F2710D132813D071 
F[StoC]: C7E7A14A19ECFC56C3BC9636BF950AC1
```

from these parameters, how can I get the `HLS-secret` with hashcat?

Comment: See https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes.  What you have is akin to mode 20 `md5($salt.$pass)`, where StoC is $salt, and you are tring to find $pass which is HLS-secret.